# Unable to query IIS from PowerShell

Tags: iis-7.5, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to use PowerShell to access and change website settings in IIS, but I've hit a blocker pretty early on.

When I use the command below, it returns only blank properties, suggesting there are no websites active on IIS on this machine:

```
New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
```

The result looks something like this...

```
ApplicationDefaults      : 
ApplicationPoolDefaults  : 
ApplicationPools         : 
SiteDefaults             : 
Sites                    : 
VirtualDirectoryDefaults : 
WorkerProcesses          :
```

...and there are no errors returned, which makes me think that the command itself is working but, for some reason, PowerShell cannot "see" the websites.

When I check in IIS Manager, I can see two webites listed in the "Sites" folder.

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine for this.

Comment: Did you try running this command from an elevated powershell prompt?

Comment: "Elevated", as in "Run as administrator"?  Yes, I tried that, but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem.

Weirdly, it seems to have been caused by the way I was loading the assembly. It didn't seem to load the assembly properly / at all (even though there was no error to tell me this):

```
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
```

However, when I loaded the assembly with this command below, the problem went away:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll") | Out-Null
```

Unfortunately, I'm still a novice to PowerShell, so I don't know why this causes a difference.